# Doxygen: Document a static C function

Tags: c, function, static, doxygen

With doxygen there is a way to include all `static` C functions in the documentation by setting `EXTRACT_STATIC` to `YES`. However, is there a way to include *only some* specific static functions in the documentation?

I managed to fool doxygen by redefining the `static` keyword and use this definition in the declaration of the functions that I want to be included in the documentation, but that's not exactly a nice way.

```
#define STATIC static
STATIC void foo(void);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it, but you just want to document only some static functions. If so you can have a look at \cond ... \cond or exclude the not to document functions by means of EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS

Comment: @albert Yes, I want to include _only some_ static functions in the documentation. I don't see how I can force doxygen to include these certain static functions via the \cond and \endcond commands. I could exclude some static functions by this if I had enabled `EXTRACT_STATIC`, but that's not feasible in my situation because there are dozens of static functions but only a few that I want to be documented.

Comment: Indeed the \cond can exclude them from the documentation. It would indeed mean that you have to enclose all the functions you don't want to document with the \cond. So it will be a bit a laborious process but to add either the non wanted static functions(patterns) to the EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS setting or to enclose the non wanted static functions in \cond construct.